# Unable to run .net core webapi webservice in IIS version 10 with a hostname

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I developed a .net core webapi webservice  that communicates with sql server database
and this runs fine locally with IIS Express within visual studio 2017. I published from visual studio 2017
to a file system and moved all files to iis.
I created a hostname in my windows 10 host file like this

127.0.0.1 testing.com

However I call my webapi like this http://testing.com:8080/api/usertbs and nothing is displayed on the
screen meaning it is not working in iis

In IIS I set my .net clr version to "No managed code" - Application pool
I installed the .Net core windows server hosting bundle.

However, I found a file named launchSettings.json in my solution and found an applicationUrl entry like this

```
        "WebApplication1": {
              "commandName": "Project",
              "launchBrowser": true,
              "launchUrl": "api/values",
              "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
              "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
              }
```

when I run this, I get a json file back which is good and means that my webapi is working

```
        http://localhost:5001/api/usertbs
```

It seems like this is running somewhere else. How can I make this run in IIS so that i can use the url
below.

```
        http://testing.com:8080/api/usertbs
```

Comment: If you have already published it to IIS, add a site binding and it should work, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: If you are referring to the binding in iis, i already did that and assigned it a host name.

Comment: Where do I add this site bindings? which file should this go ?

Comment: You are talking about IIS 10, so it is `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config`.

Comment: This is the IIS that ships with windows 10 professional edition. So I need to create the binding in the applicationhost.config file right?

Comment: I checked the file and this already exist. Any ideas on what else I can try.<site name="testapi" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="testapi">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\webapi-deployment" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:testing.com" />
                </bindings>
            </site>

Comment: Please edit your question to include important information like that.

Comment: All i get back is a blank page

Comment: IIS settings seem to be OK now.  Did you use `dotnet publish` to generate the file contents in `C:\webapi-deployment`?

Comment: Yes I did use publish.

Comment: Another useful information is when I try this http://testing.com:8080/api/values, I get the two strings returned. It must have to do with connecting with a database which I don't get.